# Change Password form, If no results

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason I can not wrap my head around this.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `strPassword` FROM cf_user WHERE `strUserId`='$username'");

    if(!$result){
        echo "The username entered does not exist!";
    }
    else {

        if($newpassword == $confirmnewpassword){
        $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE cf_user SET `strPassword` = '$newpassword' WHERE `strUserId` = '$username'");        
        }

        if(!$sql){
        echo "Congratulations, password successfully changed!";
        }
        else{
        echo "New password and confirm password must be the same!";
        }
    }
```

Everytime I get "The username entered does not exist", even if I specify the username.  I am sure !$results means not equals?  I also tried a if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0), mysql_num_rows does not exist.

I tested the sql command manually without the variables and I get a result.  I have echoed the form results and they are as expected.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This: mysql_query("SELECT `strPassword` FROM cf_user WHERE `strUserId`='$username'");
is a really really bad way for do anything about a login workflow. Even more, all is a wrong way to do anything with a password. 
Better than found an answer for this question, you must re-think the workflow again.

You never must get the pswd, the pswd is only for the DB and must still there. You can query about id or return something, but never the pswd. You never must update the pswd trought an update without validate, or a SP, or something like MD5 or any hash method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your server's php version the variables in the query may not be properly inserted.

You have:

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `strPassword` FROM cf_user WHERE `strUserId`='$username'");
```

Try using php concatenation operators(the period), might help (not being condescending, just try this out, it might be the issue.

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `strPassword` FROM cf_user WHERE `strUserId`='".$username."' ");
```

Of course this was in response to the part about you saying that it works if the variables are removed.  So I assume there is an error in your query around the variable area.

I use premiumsoft NaviCat to test my queries to make sure they work, a lot easier to troubleshoot.  You can see if your query is written correctly by saving the query in a variable and echoing it, that way you will see if it's piping in properly.

ie.

```
$query = "SELECT `strPassword` FROM cf_user WHERE `strUserId`='".$username."' ";

// echoes to browser to see final sql statement.  Don't use in production environment, and make SURE to delete then going live!!!  It will expose you database names and field names to whoever runs the function...
echo $query;

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM cf_user WHERE `strUserId`='$username' AND strPassword='".md5($password)."' LIMIT 0,1");

if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0){
    echo "The username entered does not exist!";
}
....
```

`$result` is not the actual result, it is a resource link to the result set.

From the PHP manual:

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.
>
> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc,
>   mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.
>
> The returned result resource should be passed to mysql_fetch_array(),
>   and other functions for dealing with result tables, to access the
>   returned data.
>
> Use mysql_num_rows() to find out how many rows were returned for a
>   SELECT statement or mysql_affected_rows() to find out how many rows
>   were affected by a DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, or UPDATE statement.
>
> mysql_query() will also fail and return FALSE if the user does not
>   have permission to access the table(s) referenced by the query.

Answer (score -1):

First things first: The snippet isn't coded very well.

To begin with `mysql_query` when used for `SELECT` returns a false only for an error. If there is an empty result, it will execute successfully.

When used with an `UPDATE` it returns `true` on success and false on `error`. The code seems to be making a mistake. Because when it returns a false, it is saying that you have successfully changed the password which isn't the case.

What needs to be done is:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `strPassword` FROM cf_user WHERE `strUserId`='$username'");

if ($result !== FALSE) { //not an error
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { //some rows have been returned
        if ($newPassword == $confirmPassword) {
            $query = mysql_query("UPDATE STATEMENT HERE");
            if ($query === TRUE) {
                die('Password changed');
            } else {
                die(mysql_error());
            }
        } else {
            die('Passwords don't match);
        }
    } else { //no rows returned
        die('Username not found');
    }
} else { //error
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

*Please note the above code is only a sample and I WOULD NOT recommend using it in a PROD environment. There is no input escaping.*

Answer (score -2):

try var_dump($result) to view the actual result if it is the password or not